# Is their a way to reset a Twilio device's handler function for what happens on connection Disconnect

Tags: react-redux, twilio

I could use some insight from a Twilio Evangelist. My company is using Twilio to call patients registered to our platform. The Twilio device is setup upon the user logging into the system and then they can either call a patient from their Patient Profile page or enter a manual number from their clinic's to call a prospective patient. I'm encountering an interesting error however as depending on the location the call is initiated from we want a different handler function to fire when the call is Disconnected. As it stands right now, when you first initiate a call from a Patient Profile page and pass a patientCalled object to the callPatient function the system works fine. However if you then move over to your Clinic page and initiate a call in which case patientCalled is "none, the event handler from the call initiated on the Patient Page still fires.

Can you only register an event handler to a twilio Device connection state once? Here's my code, we're running react-redux.

```
export function twilioSetup(client) {
  return async dispatch => {
    try {
      const oldToken = localStorage.getItem("twilioToken");
      if (oldToken) {
        localStorage.removeItem("twilioToken");
      }
      const response = await axios.get(`/twilio/token`);

      localStorage.setItem("twilioToken", response.data.token);

      dispatch({
        type: VERIFIED_TWILIO_CALLERIDS,
        payload: response.data.registeredCallerIds
      });

      if (!client) {
        const device = twilio.Device.setup(response.data.token, {
          codecPreferences: ["opus", "pcmu"],
          fakeLocalDTMF: true,
          debug: process.env.REACT_APP_TWILIO_DEBUG
        });

        device.on("ready", () => {
          dispatch({ type: TWILIO_DEVICE_ONLINE });
          dispatch({
            type: TWILIO_DEVICE_STATUS,
            payload: {
              device
            }
          });
        });

        device.on("offline", () => {
          dispatch({ type: TWILIO_DEVICE_OFFLINE });
          const token = localStorage.getItem("twilioToken");

          const device = twilio.Device.setup(token, {
            codecPreferences: ["opus", "pcmu"],
            fakeLocalDTMF: true,
            debug: process.env.REACT_APP_TWILIO_DEBUG
          });
          dispatch({
            type: TWILIO_DEVICE_STATUS,
            payload: {
              device
            }
          });
        });

        device.on("error", () => {
          dispatch(
            showMessage({
              message: "Error: Twilio Device Setup Failed, attempting again."
            })
          );
          dispatch({
            type: TWILIO_DEVICE_STATUS,
            payload: {
              device: null
            }
          });
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      dispatch(
        showMessage({
          message: "Twilio Voice Calls Unavailable"
        })
      );
    }
  };
}

export function callPatient(To, device, From, patientCalled) {
  if (patientCalled !== "none") {
    return dispatch => {
      const params = {
        To,
        From
      };
      device.on("connect", () => {
        const connStatus = device.status();
        if (connStatus === "busy") {
          dispatch(
            showMessage({
              message: `Calling Patient at ${phoneNumFormat(To)}`
            })
          );

          dispatch({
            type: TWILIO_CALL_STATUS,
            payload: true
          });

          dispatch({
            type: LOG_TWILIO_PATIENT,
            payload: patientCalled
          });
        }
      });

      device.on("disconnect", async conn => {
        try {
          const callID = conn.parameters.CallSid;
          const disconnStatus = device.status();
          const response = await axios.get(`/twilio/call/${callID}`);
          const callLength = Math.ceil(response.data.duration / 60);
          const plural = callLength > 1 ? "s" : "";

          if (disconnStatus === "ready") {
            dispatch({
              type: TWILIO_CALL_STATUS,
              payload: false
            });
          }

          dispatch({
            type: LOG_TWILIO_CALL,
            payload: callLength
          });

          dispatch(
            showMessage({
              message: `Call to ${phoneNumFormat(
                To
              )} Completed, Duration: ${callLength} minute${plural}`
            })
          );

          dispatch(
            openDialog({
              children: <EnterTimeDialog callLength={response.data.duration} />
            })
          );
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
            type: TWILIO_CALL_STATUS,
            payload: false
          });
        }
      });

      device.connect(params);
    };
  } else {
    return dispatch => {
      const params = {
        To,
        From
      };
      device.on("connect", () => {
        const connStatus = device.status();
        if (connStatus === "busy") {
          dispatch(
            showMessage({
              message: `Calling Patient at ${phoneNumFormat(To)}`
            })
          );
          dispatch({
            type: TWILIO_CALL_STATUS,
            payload: true
          });
        }
      });

      device.on("disconnect", async conn => {
        try {
          const callID = conn.parameters.CallSid;
          const disconnStatus = device.status();
          const response = await axios.get(`/twilio/call/${callID}`);
          const callLength = Math.ceil(response.data.duration / 60);
          const plural = callLength > 1 ? "s" : "";

          if (disconnStatus === "ready") {
            dispatch({
              type: TWILIO_CALL_STATUS,
              payload: false
            });
          }

          dispatch({
            type: LOG_TWILIO_CALL,
            payload: callLength
          });

          dispatch(
            showMessage({
              message: `Call to ${phoneNumFormat(
                To
              )} Completed, Duration: ${callLength} minute${plural}`
            })
          );
        } catch (error) {
          dispatch({
            type: TWILIO_CALL_STATUS,
            payload: false
          });
        }
      });

      device.connect(params);
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks philnash,

I actually found a different solution to my issue. Instead of starting with a new device per page I figured out how to use device.removeListner. I also discovered that to use this you can't feed the device anonymous functions for the event they have to be named so they can be fed as an argument. Here's the code that solved my problem.

```
      if (callLength > 1) {
        dispatch(
          openDialog({
            children: (
              <EnterTimeDialog callLength={response.data.duration} />
            )
          })
        );

        dispatch(
          showMessage({
            message: `Call to ${phoneNumFormat(
              To
            )} Completed, Duration: ${callLength} minute${plural}`
          })
        );
      } else {
        dispatch(
          showMessage({
            message: `Call to ${phoneNumFormat(
              To
            )} Completed, Duration: ${callLength} minute${plural}`
          })
        );
      }

      device.removeListener("disconnect", disconnectFromPatient);
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: TWILIO_CALL_STATUS,
        payload: false
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you setup the `Device` here, you are using it in singleton mode as a long lived object. Every time you make a call with the device you are then trying to add to the event listeners by calling to `device.on`. It's not that you can only attach one listener, more that you keep attaching more listeners.

There's a couple of things you can do here.

Either, you can embrace the singleton device and set up all your event listeners when you call `Device.setup`. You'll need to handle connecting and disconnecting to calls regardless of which page you are looking at.

Alternatively, you can create a new device object per page, by using the [device constructor](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device#constructor) available in version 1.5.0 and up. You can listen and react differently to different events on each device.

Let me know if that helps at all.